# API rest Pentaho

Tags: rest, api, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I need to get , with API rest call in pentaho, a list of dashboards in the public(or another) folder and if it's possible the list of datasources used in these dashboards. it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with `/repo/files/{pathId}/children` you get a list of child files from the selected repository path of the repository.

In your case `/repo/files/public/children` gives a xml that you further interpret to know if the <file> is a directory, a report, a dashboard or something else, based on its extension. You can also get the acl to know if a given user/role can see the dashboard or not.

Full documentation is [there](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Developer_Center/REST_API/File_Management/0O0), and according to my previous experience, you will need some trials and errors before to find the correct syntax and filters.

So don't give up "**YES** it is possible!".